# Java Class.forName() not working, class string loaded from property file

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, jdbc

I have a simple Java project in Eclipse, which can connect to several databases, and am trying to modify it to allow configuration of connection parameters from property file.

At current stage, I have a working `DBHelper` class, which provides a `getDatabaseConnection()` method returning a `Connection` item instantiated using hard coded parameters.

I am trying to create a similar class, which does the same but reads parameters from property file.

It is called `PropertyParser` and provides `getDBConnection()` method.

The fact is that `Class.forName()` method fails if called from this latter, even if all connection data saved in property file are **exactly** the same hard coded in `DBHelper` class, and both refer to the full class name (`oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`).

Here follows my code.

**Old working class:**

```
package mypath.helpers;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class DBHelper {
    public static Connection getDatabaseConnection(){

        String dbClass = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"; 
        String dbUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port/service"; 
        String dbUser = "user"; 
        String dbPass = "pass";

        // connect to DB
        try {
            Class.forName(dbClass);
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, dbUser, dbPass);
            con.setAutoCommit(false);
            return con;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**New not working class:**

```
package mypath.helpers;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class PropertyParser extends Properties{

    // variables 
    private static String propFile = "conf/myprops.properties";
    private static String dbClassProp = "DBCLASS"; 
    private static String dbUrlProp = "DBURL"; 
    private static String dbUserProp = "DBUSER"; 
    private static String dbPassProp = "DBPASS";

    // constructor
    public PropertyParser() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

        super();
        this.load(new FileInputStream(propFile));
    }

    public Connection getDBConnection() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{

        // read properties
        String JDBCClass = this.getProperty(dbClassProp).trim() ; 
        String JDBCUrl = this.getProperty(dbUrlProp).trim();
        String JDBCUserId = this.getProperty(dbUserProp).trim();
        String JDBCPasswd = this.getProperty(dbPassProp).trim();

        Class.forName(JDBCClass);
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBCUrl, JDBCUserId, JDBCPasswd);
        con.setAutoCommit(false);

        return con;
    }
}
```

And here's the main, whith both calls:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        // this works fine
        Connection con = DBHelper.getDatabaseConnection();
        System.out.println("Everything works fine till now.");

        // this does not work
        PropertyParser pp = new PropertyParser();
        Connection con2 = pp.getDBConnection();
        System.out.println("I will never reach this point.");
    }
```

And here's the output i get:

```
Everything works fine till now.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at mypath.helpers.PropertyParser.getDBConnection(PropertyParser.java:35)
    at mypath.GetConnection.main(GetConnection.java:20)
```

ojdbc.jar file is configured in the build path of the project. Is there a way to accomplish the result?

Comment: Is the `ojdbc.jar`available on the `CLASSPATH` too?

Comment: what is Properties class doing? Please paste that as well

Comment: @djames Properties class is the standard java.util.Properties.

Comment: sorry...i missed the import.

Comment: @N00bPr0grammer i tried adding ojdbc.jar file to "Run as" > "Run Configurations" > "Classpath" tab, without success.

Comment: show your `conf/myprops.properties`  file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is shown in the expection message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: **"oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"**

If I write

```
    Class.forName("HelloWorld");
```

I get the following exception message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: **HelloWorld**

Somehow your properties file contains not the class name, but the class name enclosed in quotes.

Strip of those quotes and your code will work.

Comment: Obvious things are the worst! Many thanks, I was getting crazy :)

Answer (score 3):

Double quotes. 
You don't have to put double quotes in properties values.

so its:
`DBCLASS=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`

and not 
`DBCLASS="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"`

Answer (score 0):

See if there is an `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` class in `ojdbc.jar`.

In simple ways, it is an import for the class with the fully qualified name `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` and see is it report an error in your eclipse.